# Button text is hidden under specific conditions

Tags: android

I am currently working on an app which needs to load a user's inventory from WAX ExpressTrade.

I got that down, and am now working on displaying the item to a user, but I noticed some weird interferences.

I have a button which simply says "Add Item" (for adding the item you are previewing to a trade). This function also appeared to be working until I recently purchased a new item.

When this new item (Dual Berettas | Assassin) is displayed, the button text appears.

I have been debugging a lot, and have found that:

- The item name is responsible of the disappearance (somehow).
- The item name must be long enough to wrap the item condition to the next line (Items are displayed as "Dual Berettas | Assassin (Battle-Scarred)").
- There must not be more than 2 spaces after the | (namely, the space after "|" and before the parenthesis). This means that "Dual Berettas | Assassin Test (Battle-Scarred)" will cause the text to actually display.

I hope I was understandable.

Here is my code for displaying the item:

```
        final JSONObject item = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("item"));
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
        ImageView close = new ImageView(this);
        close.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp, null));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams closeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        closeParams.gravity = Gravity.END;
        close.setLayoutParams(closeParams);
        close.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }
        });
        layout.addView(close);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imgParams.leftMargin = 10;
        imgParams.rightMargin = 10;
        new ImageDownloader(img, 600, 600).execute(item.getJSONObject("image").getString("600px"));
        img.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
        layout.addView(img);
        if(item.has("in_offer") && item.getBoolean("in_offer")) {
            LinearLayout inOffer = new LinearLayout(this);
            inOffer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ImageView warning = new ImageView(this);
            warning.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_priority_high_white_24dp, null));
            inOffer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dc3545"));
            TextView inOfferText = new TextView(this);
            inOfferText.setText(R.string.in_offer);
            inOffer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            inOffer.addView(warning);
            inOffer.addView(inOfferText);
            layout.addView(inOffer);
        }
        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        name.setText(item.getString("name"));
        name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(name);
        if(item.has("wear")) {
            TextView wear = new TextView(this);
            wear.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.wear, item.get("wear").toString()));
            wear.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            layout.addView(wear);
        }
        TextView price = new TextView(this);
        double usdprice = ((double)item.getInt("suggested_price")) / 100.0;
        price.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.price, Double.toString(usdprice)));
        price.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(price);
        Button add = new Button(this);
        add.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#007bff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams addParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        add.setLayoutParams(addParams);
        add.setPadding(100, 50, 100, 50);
        add.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("item", item.toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        add.setText(R.string.add_item);
        add.setTextSize(14);
        layout.addView(add);
```

Please note that the ImageView called img is of the dimensions 600x600 (I don't know if this is relevant), and if it is not present, the text displays fine aswell.

Here you can see that the text displays fine on this item (image 1)[image: successful display], where the layout has the completely same height as the failing one (image 2)[image: failing display]

Comment: Some screenshots may be helpful.

Comment: Even I can't get the question! it's too bulky...

Comment: @Vucko Added in screenshots.

Comment: @W.Seun I understand, I don't really know how to explain it any better.
Basically: The button text is gone in some cases, in other cases, it is not.
I added screenshots, maybe those will help with understanding.

Comment: Add the layout code for the dialog that pops up. Come on man, you have to think what we might need.

Comment: @Vucko Everything is done programmatically, you have the code.

Comment: The problem may be this `add.setPadding(100, 50, 100, 50);`, it's too much padding top/bottom, reduce that.

Comment: @Vucko I added the padding as an attempt to solve the problem.
Additionally, I don't see how the padding only messes up in this one case, and not all of them.

Comment: Well this is quite a weird bug. The name that it DOES NOT appear on is actually shorter than some that it does, right? Try putting "Add" instead of "Add item", shorten the button text. See if that has anything to do with it. Reduce text size, play around with it to see what's causing it. I don't know what more I could tell ya :/

Answer (score 0):

remove    `add.setPadding(100, 50, 100, 50);` and try to build agin. Most probably your padding disspear that button text

If it relates to image, you can try glide. It will resolve that resolution and performance issues. https://github.com/bumptech/glide is the repository.

```
 GlideApp.with(this).load("https...").into(imageView);
```

try this as well

Comment: Adding the padding was actually an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: did it only happens when you click that second item ? do u follow any order while clicking these items?

Comment: It is only on the "Dual Berettas | Assassin", no matter if I press it first, second, third and so on.

I also tried setting the name statically (no matter what the actual item was) to "Dual Berettas | Assassin", and the problem would then occur with all items.

Comment: @ItzBenteThePig i updated my answer. please try this. most probably it will solve your problem, if it relates to image